# Unable to execute PHP files from the command line

Tags: php, command-line, ubuntu-14.04, command-line-interface, php-7

After I got an issue with Jenkins, that the deployment is hanging up on jobs, that need to execute PHP on the command line (`pdepend`, `phpmd`, `phpcpd` etc.), and noticed, that I also cannot re-install Composer or run tools like PHPLoc on the command line, I created a PHP file

```
<?php
print_r(get_defined_constants());
```

and tried to execute it on the command line:

```
php phptest.php
```

And it didn't work. When I do so, nothing happens. No errors. Just nothing:

[image]

The environment is PHP `7.0.3` and Ubuntu `14.04.3` (in a VirtualBox VM). Btw. `php -v` or `php -i` executed on the command line is still working.

**What might cause this issue and how to solve it?**

**EDIT**

The **permissions** seem to be correct:

```
root@ubuntuvm:~/Desktop# ls -lia | grep "phptest.php"
132234 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   40 Aug  2 17:29 phptest.php
```

`777` is also not working:

```
root@ubuntuvm:~/Desktop# chmod 777 ./phptest.php 
root@ubuntuvm:~/Desktop# php phptest.php
^C
```

The error reporting is set up:

**`/etc/php/7.0/cli`**

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
log_errors = On
error_log = /var/log/php_errors.log
```

Comment: Is there no output at all? Does the script hang or does it complete execution with no output?

Comment: The script hangs up and doesn't complete the execution. There is no output, just a line break (made by the OS -- so absolutely no output generated by the PHP script). See the screenshot, I've just added to the question.

Comment: That's weird. Are the permissions for your php file correct? Is it locked to just the www-data user? Also are the permissions correct? Usually 644 (rw-rw-r--)

Comment: PHP is throwing an error, but error output is disabled. So appears like nothing is happening. Check your PHP logs or update your PHP.ini to output errors.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia is probably right!! Check the logs or add:
    `error_reporting(E_ALL);`
    `ini_set("display_errors", 1);`
To your code

Comment: @DrRoach Yes, the permissions seem to be OK. See the update above.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia The error reporintg is set up, see the update above.

Comment: Hmm, can you run the script with `sudo`?

Comment: @automatix if there are no errors, then maybe nothing is wrong. Try adding echo statements before and after the `print_r` as it might be outputting an empty string.

Comment: @DrRoach I'm `root` on the system (it's a local VM).

Comment: @ThinkingMedia I tried `print_r(get_defined_constants());` (see the question) and also things like `die('###')`. If everything is correct, such scripts must generate an output.

Comment: Make sure the PHP file is not unicode with a unicode prefix byte.

Comment: Does the command work if you run PHP in interactive mode? `php -a`

Comment: Try the file option as well. `php -f <filename.php>`

Comment: Try this: `php -n -r "print_r(get_defined_constants());"` and I'm running out of ideas. lol

Comment: @ThinkingMedia Yes, the interactive mode is working.

Comment: Everything is working again! I really have not changed anything at the system! Just restarted the VM. I have no idea, why it's working now... I simply installed another VM and the old one got another IP. But that's all -- and it cannot affect the behavior of PHP!..

Comment: @automatix this is obviously Microsoft's fault and a Windows problem. lol

Comment: @ThinkingMedia Exactly -- a Microsoft's fault and a Windows problem on a Linux VM... :)

Comment: This is happening to me now. :( What the hell is going on?! I even just made a one line php that just has `print "wtf\n";` and when I try to run that from the command line it just hangs.

Answer (score 11):

This just started happening to me and I finally figured it out. I don't know if this was your problem or if you can replicate it, but hopefully this may help somebody else.

I had two projects open in PHPStorm and in one of those projects I had turned on "Listen for PHP Debug Connections" and due to some configuration option, as soon as I ran ANY php script anywhere on my system, that one PHPStorm window would grab the process and halt it for debugging.

[image]

Normally, this would cause PHPStorm to jump forward to be the top-most window to give me a visual cue that it can taken control, but due to the type of script I was running I was immediately switching windows after starting it. So my manual window switching made me not notice PHPStorm's auto-switch.

After making PHPStorm stop listening for connections, I was able to run scripts again.